# How do I map a variable to aes fill in geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Conceptually I thought a point would be dimensionless but I saw in the documentation that `geom_point` actually takes the aesthetic `fill`. However it doesn't seem to work for me:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp, fill = carb))
```

[image]

The aesthetics seems to be ignored, by I would expect a warning similarly to `geom_line`:

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) + geom_line(aes(mpg, disp, fill = carb))
```

> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill

Comment: @MauritsEvers thanks. Should I delete?

Comment: [Best to not delete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate); your question will be flagged and closed as a dupe within the next few hours, but will still help others here on SO with similar problems by acting as a sign post.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `pch` to a value that can take both `color` and `fill` it will work.

`ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3, pch = 21, fill = "grey", color = "darkred")`

[image]